# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in Angular 4

Tags: angular, laravel-5

when i run `ng build --prod` version then showing below error.

```
ERROR in RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at /var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1684:33
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at _CompileValueConverter.ValueTransformer.visitArray (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1684:20)
at visitValue (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1648:24)
at extractIdentifiers (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16270:5)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16071:9)
at /var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16036:83
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15999:19)
at /var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16001:23
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15999:19)
at /var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15574:63
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15565:49)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/var/www/html/projectName/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15507:52)
```

i am using angular 
@angular/cli: 1.4.4, node: 8.9.0, npm : 5.5.1

Comment: Do you mean it is working fine with `ng build --dev` command??

Comment: Yes, but when i run in production version then not working

Comment: please try ng serve --aot to debug this, try to delete imports that you don't need

Comment: i already use this command but this one is also showing same error

Comment: did you try a build with --build-optimizer=false ??

Comment: yes, this one is working fine. But need to run `ng build --prod` version

Comment: ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false

Comment: just run this command but showing same error :(